To run nginx as a non root user in GKE - nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine-slim - on privileged port 80
https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged
States that

The default NGINX listen port is now 8080 instead of 80 (this is no
longer necessary as of Docker 20.03 but it's still required in other
container runtimes).

Does anyone know what does this equates to in terms of GKE version?
My need: To run nginx as a non root user. I came across this image nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine-slim rather than muzzling with a bunch of chmod 755 or chown with the usual nginx image. Now I would like to know whether I can use port 80 in GKE (say we are on 1.29) or should I switch to non-privileged ports like 8080
